# Android: Lock Portrait mode for 5 seconds then allow screen orientation change

Tags: android, timer, orientation, landscape-portrait

Is this possible? I currently have intent that is activated when the orientation changes but after some testing it is a problem if the phone is in landscape mode when going the new class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not.  You would need to do it programmatically though.   My first thought is to create an activity with a runnable.  In your onCreate, lock the orientation that you want and kick off the runnable thread.   In the runnable thread, wait 5 seconds and then unlock the orientation.